# How to fix "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (55161)" for conditionally coloring histogtam?

Tags: r

I have a dataset such as this:

```
Store    ZScore
A        1
B        1
C        3
D        2
E        5
F        4
```

And I am trying to create a histogram grouped by the store, and color each cell whether they are an outlier, or not an outlier.

But I am running into this error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (55161): colour, fill
```

But I am running into an error when I use an ifelse statement for fill and color.

```
histo_store <- ggplot(df, aes(ZScore, group = df$Store)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05, 
             colour = ifelse(ZScore >= -3 & ZScore <= 3, "black", "gray") 
             fill = ifelse(ZScore >= -3 & ZScore <= 3, "gray", "orange")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1, colour="#333333") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3, size = 1, colour="#333333", linetype = 
"dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -3, size = 1, colour="#333333", linetype = 
"dotted") +
  bbc_style() +
  labs(title = "Distribution of Z-Scores for Percent Change among Stores")
```

The end result should color each store and outline it based on what the z-score is.

Comment: It's hard to tell since you don't include your data, but the `color` and `fill` aesthetics in `geom_histogram` should be in an `aes` function. Normally you'd get an `object 'ZScore' not found` error, but if you have an object in your environment called `ZScore` it would use that (not the ZScore variable in df), possible resultin in a vector of incorrect length.

Comment: To get a real answer, you should include a [mcve] of your dataset using the `dput` function.